# JavaScript touch event that triggers when finger over a child element

Tags: javascript

With a mousedown event I can can trigger events for child element with a mouseover as I drag the mouse to select child elements. With touch events I cannot figure out how to trigger an event when the user touches the screen and drags their finger over child element like how you can with mouse events.

What I have working with the mouse is when the user click on an area with multiple child elements they can then drag the mouse over the child element they wish to select. With touch events there does not seem to be any event that is triggered for the child element as the users finger is dragged over any of the children like with mouseover events.

Comment: Touch events are usually translated automatically into analogous mouse events. So `mouseenter` and `mouseover` events should still work.

Comment: @Barmar They don't seem to be in the Chrome dev tools, haven't tried on a real touch device yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in observing that touch events don't work the same way as mouse events. However, you can still achieve the desired behavior with a combination of touch events.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Start by tracking touch movements when the user touches the screen (touchstart and touchmove).
2. On each movement (touchmove), get the position of the touch event.
3. Determine which child element is under that position.
4. Trigger the desired event for that child element.

Here's example

```
let isTouching = false;

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    isTouching = true;
    handleTouchMove(event.touches[0]); // Handle the initial touch point as well
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    if (isTouching) {
        handleTouchMove(event.touches[0]);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    isTouching = false;
});

function handleTouchMove(touch) {
    const touchedElement = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
    
    // Assuming you're looking for child elements of a specific parent container
    const parentContainer = document.querySelector('#yourParentContainerId');
    if (parentContainer.contains(touchedElement)) {
        // Trigger your desired event for the touchedElement
        console.log('Touched over:', touchedElement);
        // If you want to dispatch a custom event:
        // touchedElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('customEventName'));
    }
}
```

The above code will output the child element under the touch point every time the touch moves.